# NDSolve: there are more variables than equations, underdet

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, numerical-integration

I am working on using NDSolve to solve coupled ODE. The following is the coupled equations.[image] It works fine for sever orders. I used table to generate like 962 couple variables and equations, where the NDSolve can still work out. However my goal is to further quantize the system and generate an even larger basis, like around 5000 coupled variables. But after I did that, The NDSolve did not work out anymore with error message like "There are more variable, underdet". I am kind of sure (not completely sure) the amount of variable equals the amount of  coupled equations. I am wondering is there any upper limit for the size of the coupled ODE the NDSolve can calculate? I am kind of feeling it is up to 1000 variables.

the following is the code:

```
\[Omega] = 
  2 \[Pi]*73.5*^3(*2\[Pi]*73.5*^3 Hz, the mass of lithium is low.*);
\[Delta]eff = -2 \[Pi]*200*^3(*-2\[Pi]*200*^3*); 
na = 1*10^5*2.3; (*6 Default 2*10^5 *)
\[CapitalDelta]0 = -2 \[Pi]*0.2(*light shift per photon, which is \
-Subscript[g, 0]^2/Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], a]*)(* Default \
-2\[Pi]*0.2 *);
\[Kappa] = 2 \[Pi]*126*^3;(*2\[Pi]*126*^3*)
a = 2.8;(*10*)

\[CapitalDelta]t = 0.0000005;
t0 = 0.00005;

maxkc = 2;
maxkf = maxkc*0.5*1.75;
nn = 7
deltak = maxkf/nn
nc = maxkc*0.5/deltak


\[Mu] = maxkf^2 + maxkf^2; (* chemical potential, depends on maxkf *)


kT = \[Mu]/10; (* set temperature *)
coef = (* Fermi distribution with normalization process *)
 Module[{coefficient}, 
  coefficient /. 
   Flatten[Solve[
     Sum[coefficient/(
       Exp[((deltak*i)^2 + (deltak*j)^2 - \[Mu])/kT] + 
        1), {i, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, 
        nn + nc + nc}] == 1, coefficient]]]
initialvalues = 
  Array[ini, {31, 
    31}, {{-nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}, {-nn - nc - nc, 
     nn + nc + nc}}];
Do[initialvalues[[i, j]] = (coef/(
   Exp[((deltak*(i - 1 - nn - nc - nc))^2 + (deltak*(j - 1 - nn - nc -
             nc))^2 - \[Mu])/kT] + 1))^(1/2), {i, 1, 
  2*(nn + nc + nc) + 1}, {j, 1, 2*(nn + nc + nc) + 1}]
initialvalues // MatrixForm;
initialvalues[[16, 16]]
ListPlot[initialvalues[[16, 16 ;; 31]], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full]


SetSystemOptions[
 "NDSolveOptions" -> {"DefaultScanDiscontinuityTimeConstraint" -> 
    100.`, "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> 1000.`}]


odes = Flatten[{
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 12,
      12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t], {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 12,
      11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 12,
      10 to 12,-10 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][
          t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn, nn}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 
      12,-11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 
      12,-12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t], {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 11,
      11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 11,
      10 to 11,-10 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][
          t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, -nn, nn}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 
      11,-11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*(
         Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]],
   
   (*10,10 to -10,-10 BIGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG LOOP*)
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] == \[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][
          t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]) + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, -nn, nn}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] == (* -11,-11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, i*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*(
         Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* -11,
      10 to -11,-10 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][
          t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t])
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*(
         Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]),
     {i, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}, {j, -nn, nn}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* -11,
      11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*(
         Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] == (* -12,-12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t], {i, -nn - 
       nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] == (* -12,-11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] == (* -12,-10 to -12,
      10 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][
          t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t])
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, -nn, nn}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* -12,
      11 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* -12,
      12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t], {i, -nn - 
       nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 11,
      12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 10,
      12 to -10,
      12 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t])
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* -11,
      12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 10,
      11 to -10,
      11 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t])
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 
      10,-11 to -10,-11 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*
            deltak)^2 - 1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t])
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] == (* -11,-12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 
      10,-12 to -10,-12 LOOP *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*
            deltak)^2 - 1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t])
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]],
   
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] == (* 
      11,-12 *)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]
       - 1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t]
       + 1/
        2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
          a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]],
   
   I*\[Beta]'[t] == (-\[Delta]eff + 1/2*na*\[CapitalDelta]0*
           
         Sum[Re[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]*
            Conjugate[
             Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]]], {i, -nn -
             nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, nn}] - 
        I*\[Kappa])*\[Beta][t] - 
     I*1/8*na*\[CapitalDelta]0*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a)^0.5
      *(
       Sum[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t](*-12 to 11,12*)
           *Conjugate[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]]
          + Conjugate[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]]
           *
           Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t], {i, -nn -
            nc - nc, nn + nc}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]
        
        + 
        Sum[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][
            t]*(Conjugate[
              Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]] + 
             Conjugate[
              Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][
               t]])(*-12 to 11, -11 to 11*)
          + 
          Conjugate[
            Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][
             t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
             Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][
              t]), {i, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc, nn + nc}]
        
        + 
        Sum[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][
            t](*-12 to 11, -12*)
           *Conjugate[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]]
          + Conjugate[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]]
           *
           Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t], {i, -nn -
            nc - nc, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}])}]
Text[Style[
  "There are " <> ToString[Dimensions[odes]] <> 
   " coupled differential equations", Red, 18, Italic]]


ics = Flatten[{Table[
     Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][0] == 
      initialvalues[[i + nn + nc + nc + 1, 
       j + nn + nc + nc + 1]], {i, -nn - nc - nc, 
      nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}],
    
    (*Table[Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.3,{i,-nn,
    nn},{j,-nn,nn}],Table[Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][
    0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,nn+1,nn+nc+nc},{j,-nn-nc-nc,nn+nc+nc}],
    Table[Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,-nn-
    nc-nc,-nn-1},{j,-nn-nc-nc,nn+nc+nc}],
    Table[Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,-nn,
    nn},{j,nn+1,nn+nc+nc}],
    Table[Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,-nn,
    nn},{j,-nn-nc-nc,-nn-1}],*)
    
    \[Beta][0] == 0}];
Text[Style[
  "There are " <> ToString[Dimensions[ics]] <> 
   " initial condition equations", Red, 18, Italic]]



variable = 
  Flatten[ {\[Beta], 
    Flatten[Table[
      Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak], {i, -nn - nc - nc, 
       nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}]]}];
Text[Style["There are " <> ToString[Dimensions[ics]] <> " variables", 
  Red, 18, Italic]]



solve = NDSolve[{odes, ics}, variable, {t, 0, 0.0001}];
```

I generated coupled equations, initial conditions and variables separately before using NDSolve.
nn and nc are used to control the order of the couple equations.

deltak needs to be either 0.1,0.2,0.25,0.5 or 1. (it has to be something periodic within 1)
maxkc needs to be 2.
maxkf needs to be 1.5 (although here I used 1.75).

Thus there are some combinations between nn and nc. Current the limit is nn=6, thus nc =4, and the order is (2*(6+4+4)+1)^2 = (29)^2 =841;

But if I use nn=15, thus nc =10, the order is (2*(15+10+10)+1)^2 = (71)^2 = 5041, the NDSolve gave error: more varibles and underdet.

Can someone have a look at this problem?

Best

Answer (score 3):

There are several typos in the code. First, initial data array probably should be in a form

```
initialvalues =  Array[ini, {2 (nn + nc + nc) + 1,  2 (nn + nc + nc) + 1}, {{-nn - nc - nc,      nn + nc + nc}, {-nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}}]
```

It could be better to use  `ArrayPlot[initialvalues]` for initial data visualization, then we can see all initial values. Second, don't use   `Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]` with real induces. It could be better to use it with rational induces. For example, let put `deltak = 1/10` then we have

```
Clear["Global`*"]

\[Omega] = 
  2 \[Pi]*73.5*^3(*2\[Pi]*73.5*^3 Hz,the mass of lithium is low.*);
\[Delta]eff = -2 \[Pi]*200*^3(*-2\[Pi]*200*^3*);
na = 1*10^5*2.3;(*6 Default 2*10^5*)\[CapitalDelta]0 = -2 \
\[Pi]*0.2(*light shift per photon,which \
is-Subscript[g,0]^2/Subscript[\[CapitalDelta],a]*)(*Default-2\[Pi]*0.\
2*);
\[Kappa] = 
 2 \[Pi]*126*^3;(*2\[Pi]*126*^3*)a = 2.8;(*10*)\[CapitalDelta]t = \
0.0000005;
t0 = 0.00005;

maxkc = 2;
maxkf = maxkc*0.5*1.75;
nn = 15;
deltak = 1/10;
nc = maxkc*1/2/deltak;


\[Mu] = maxkf^2 + 
  maxkf^2;(*chemical potential,depends on maxkf*)kT = \[Mu]/
  10;(*set temperature*)coef =(*Fermi distribution with normalization \
process*)Module[{coefficient}, 
  coefficient /. 
   Flatten[Solve[
     Sum[coefficient/(Exp[((deltak*i)^2 + (deltak*j)^2 - \[Mu])/kT] + 
          1), {i, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, 
        nn + nc + nc}] == 1, coefficient]]];
initialvalues = 
  Array[ini, {2 (nn + nc + nc) + 1, 
    2 (nn + nc + nc) + 1}, {{-nn - nc - nc, 
     nn + nc + nc}, {-nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}}];
Do[initialvalues[[i, 
    j]] = (coef/(Exp[((deltak*(i - 1 - nn - nc - 
                 nc))^2 + (deltak*(j - 1 - nn - nc - nc))^2 - \[Mu])/
          kT] + 1))^(1/2), {i, 1, 2*(nn + nc + nc) + 1}, {j, 1, 
   2*(nn + nc + nc) + 1}];
initialvalues // MatrixForm;
ArrayPlot[initialvalues, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "NDSolveOptions" -> {"DefaultScanDiscontinuityTimeConstraint" -> 
     100.`, "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> 1000.`}];



odes = Flatten[{Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*12,
      12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t], {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*12,
      11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*12,
      10 to 12,-10 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][
           t] + Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn, nn}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*12,-11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*12,-12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t], {i, 
      nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*11,
      11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*11,
      10 to 11,-10 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][
           t] + Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, -nn, nn}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*11,-11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]],(*10,
   10 to-10,-10 BIGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG LOOP*)
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] == \[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][
           t] + Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]) + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, -nn, nn}]], 
   Flatten[
    Table[I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*-11,-11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, i*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*-11,
      10 to-11,-10 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][
           t] + Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, -nn, nn}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*-11,
      11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*-12,-12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t], {i, -nn - 
       nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*-12,-11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*-12,-10 to-12,
      10 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*
        Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][
           t] + Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t]) - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, -nn, nn}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*-12,
      11*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*-12,
      12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][t]]*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t], {i, -nn - 
       nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*11,
      12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*10,12 to-10,
      12 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]) + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*-11,
      12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[t] ==(*10,11 to-10,
      11 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak - 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]) + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, nn + 1, nn + nc}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*10,-11 to-10,-11 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*
             deltak)^2 - 1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]) + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, -nn - nc, -nn - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*-11,-12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn -
        nc, -nn - 1}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*10,-12 to-10,-12 LOOP*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*
             deltak)^2 - 1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
        a*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 2, j*deltak][t]) + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, -nn, 
      nn}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     I*Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak]'[
        t] ==(*11,-12*)\[Omega]*((i*deltak)^2 + (j*deltak)^2 - 
          1/2*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2 - 
          1/2*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a))*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*Abs[\[Beta][t]]^2*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t] - 
       1/4*\[Omega]*(Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*a*
        Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 2, j*deltak][t] + 
       1/2*\[Omega]*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
           a)^0.5 Im[\[Beta][
          t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
          Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak - 1, j*deltak + 1][t]), {i, 
      nn + 1, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}]], 
   I*\[Beta]'[
      t] == (-\[Delta]eff + 
        1/2*na*\[CapitalDelta]0*
         Sum[Re[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]*
            
            Conjugate[
             Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak + 2][t]]], {i, -nn -
             nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, nn}] - 
        I*\[Kappa])*\[Beta][t] - 
     I*1/8*na*\[CapitalDelta]0*((Tanh[(t - t0)/\[CapitalDelta]t] + 1)*
         a)^0.5*(Sum[
         Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t](*-12 to 11,12*)*
           Conjugate[
            Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t]] + 
          Conjugate[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]]*
           Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][t], {i, -nn -
            nc - nc, nn + nc}, {j, nn + nc + 1, nn + nc + nc}] + 
        Sum[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][
            t]*(Conjugate[
              Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]] + 
             Conjugate[
              Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][
               t]])(*-12 to 11,-11 to 11*)+ 
          Conjugate[
            Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][
             t]]*(Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t] + 
             Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak - 1][
              t]), {i, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc, 
          nn + nc}] + 
        Sum[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t](*-12 to 11,-12*)*
           Conjugate[
            Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t]] + 
          Conjugate[Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][t]]*
           Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak + 1, j*deltak + 1][t], {i, -nn -
            nc - nc, nn + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, -nn - nc - 1}])}]
Text[Style[
  "There are " <> ToString[Dimensions[odes]] <> 
   " coupled differential equations", Red, 18, Italic]]


ics = Flatten[{Table[
     Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak][0] == 
      initialvalues[[i + nn + nc + nc + 1, 
       j + nn + nc + nc + 1]], {i, -nn - nc - nc, 
      nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}],(*Table[
    Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.3,{i,-nn,
    nn},{j,-nn,nn}],Table[Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][
    0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,nn+1,nn+nc+nc},{j,-nn-nc-nc,nn+nc+nc}],Table[
    Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,-nn-nc-
    nc,-nn-1},{j,-nn-nc-nc,nn+nc+nc}],Table[Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,
    j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,-nn,nn},{j,nn+1,nn+nc+nc}],Table[
    Subscript[\[Phi],i*deltak,j*deltak][0]\[Equal]0.02,{i,-nn,
    nn},{j,-nn-nc-nc,-nn-1}],*)\[Beta][0] == 0}];
Text[Style[
  "There are " <> ToString[Dimensions[ics]] <> 
   " initial condition equations", Red, 18, Italic]]



variable = 
  Flatten[{\[Beta], 
    Flatten[Table[
      Subscript[\[Phi], i*deltak, j*deltak], {i, -nn - nc - nc, 
       nn + nc + nc}, {j, -nn - nc - nc, nn + nc + nc}]]}];
Text[Style["There are " <> ToString[Dimensions[ics]] <> " variables", 
  Red, 18, Italic]]
solve = NDSolve[{odes, ics}, variable, {t, 0, 0.0001}];

Plot[Abs[\[Beta][t]] /. solve, {t, 0, 0.0001}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 2]